# Android build failing in Jenkins due to connectedAndroidTestDebug TimeoutException

Tags: android-testing

My current Jenkins build is failing when trying to deploy tests on a real android device.

I have found some people having a similar issue on Travis, but I could not find many others reporting it in Jenkins.

As you can see in the error outputed by gradle this is caused by the TimeoutException triggered when attempting to install the tests:

```
:library:connectedAndroidTestDebug
11:20:37 E/Device: Error during Sync: timeout.
Unable to install /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/WORKSPACE_PATH/build/outputs/apk/library-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:853)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:91)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:769)
    at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.doPushFile(SyncService.java:695)
    at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.pushFile(SyncService.java:380)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.syncPackageToDevice(Device.java:1069)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:844)
    ... 9 more

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > runTests[Nexus 4 - 4.4.4] [31mFAILED [0m
    com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
        at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:95)
null
com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:95)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:853)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:91)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:769)
    at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.doPushFile(SyncService.java:695)
    at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.pushFile(SyncService.java:380)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.syncPackageToDevice(Device.java:1069)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:844)
    ... 9 more
:library:connectedAndroidTestDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I tried invoking Gradle Wrapper which made no difference to specifying the version in the job configuration - I tried Gradle 2.5-rc-1, Gradle 2.3 and Gradle 2.2.1, this last one worked for two builds and then started returning this same timeout error.

I also tried setting up environmental variable:

```
export ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=10
```

Setting in build.gradle the com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences.setTimeOut param:

```
com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences.setTimeOut(60000)
```

Also tried using the adbOption 'timeOutInMs' which neither worked.

```
android {
    adbOptions {
        timeOutInMs 60000 // set timeout to 1 minute
    }
}
```

It looks like this is an ongoing issue in code.google.com - the following two threads seem to be connected to it:

- Issue 1: [com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.getDeviceConfig has a hard coded timeout value that is too low](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189764)
- Issue 2: [Allow the user to increase the ADB timeout](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=104305)

Any ideas what else could I try?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed it [restarting the adb server](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#stopping) and issuing any other adb command like for example requesting the list of devices.

Just run the following commands from the terminal:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Did not work for me.