# Android instrumentation test fails to install APK

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-instrumentation

I want to run instrumentation test as part of my CI pipeline but when I run the tests they fail because the APK could not be installed (as far as I understood):

```
> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
Mar 18, 2022 3:00:59 PM com.google.testing.platform.RunnerImpl run
SEVERE: Test execution failed with fatal error!
com.google.testing.platform.api.plugin.PluginException: Exception thrown during onBeforeAll invocation of plugin com.google.testing.platform.plugin.android.AndroidDevicePlugin.
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycleKt.invokeOrThrow(PluginLifecycle.kt:216)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycleKt.invokeOrThrow$default(PluginLifecycle.kt:205)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycle$onBeforeAll$1.invoke(PluginLifecycle.kt:92)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycle$onBeforeAll$1.invoke(PluginLifecycle.kt:88)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.common.noop.NoopDiagnosticsScope.recordEvent(NoopDiagnosticsScope.kt:35)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent(Telemetry.kt:105)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent$default(Telemetry.kt:98)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycle.onBeforeAll(PluginLifecycle.kt:88)
        at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor$execute$4.invoke(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:86)
        at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor$execute$4.invoke(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:86)
        at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor.runUnlessCancelled(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:105)
        at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor.execute(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:86)
        at com.google.testing.platform.RunnerImpl.run(RunnerImpl.kt:108)
        at com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy$run$4.invoke(NonInteractiveServerStrategy.kt:80)
        at com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy$run$4.invoke(NonInteractiveServerStrategy.kt:79)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.common.noop.NoopDiagnosticsScope.recordEvent(NoopDiagnosticsScope.kt:35)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent(Telemetry.kt:66)
        at com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy.run(NonInteractiveServerStrategy.kt:79)
        at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt$main$4.invokeSuspend(Main.kt:67)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt.main(Main.kt:66)
        at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt.main$default(Main.kt:34)
        at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.google.testing.platform.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:149)
Caused by: com.google.testing.platform.core.error.UtpException: ErrorName: UNKNOWN
NameSpace: DdmlibAndroidDeviceController
ErrorCode: 1
Message: Failed to install APKs: UNKNOWN
        at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.deviceprovider.ddmlib.DdmlibAndroidDeviceController$executeAsync$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(DdmlibAndroidDeviceController.kt:197)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing 'install':
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.pm.PackageManagerInternal.freeStorage(java.lang.String, long, int)' on a null object reference
at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.allocateBytes(StorageManagerService.java:4033)
at android.os.storage.StorageManager.allocateBytes(StorageManager.java:2340)
at android.os.storage.StorageManager.allocateBytes(StorageManager.java:2419)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerSession.doWriteInternal(PackageInstallerSession.java:1556)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerSession.write(PackageInstallerSession.java:1469)
at android.content.pm.PackageInstaller$Session.write(PackageInstaller.java:1045)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doWriteSplit(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3338)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doWriteSplits(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3300)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doRunInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1351)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1303)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:193)
at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:24742)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:950)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:834)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4818)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:8839)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1184)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1143)
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installRemotePackage(DeviceImpl.java:1314)
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1140)
        at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.deviceprovider.ddmlib.DdmlibAndroidDevice.installPackage(DdmlibAndroidDevice.kt)
        at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.deviceprovider.ddmlib.DdmlibAndroidDeviceController$executeAsync$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(DdmlibAndroidDeviceController.kt:166)
        ... 6 more

Mar 18, 2022 3:00:59 PM com.android.tools.utp.plugins.host.additionaltestoutput.AndroidAdditionalTestOutputPlugin deviceShellAndCheckSuccess
WARNING: Shell command failed (1): ls "/sdcard/Android/media/xxxxx/additional_test_output"
ls: /sdcard/Android/media/xxxxx/additional_test_output: No such file or directory

Mar 18, 2022 3:00:59 PM com.android.tools.utp.plugins.host.additionaltestoutput.AndroidAdditionalTestOutputPlugin afterAll
WARNING: Failed to retrieve additional test outputs from device.
com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!
        at com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.pullFile(SyncService.java:341)
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.pullFile(DeviceImpl.java:1083)
        at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.deviceprovider.ddmlib.DdmlibAndroidDevice.pullFile(DdmlibAndroidDevice.kt)
        at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.deviceprovider.ddmlib.DdmlibAndroidDeviceController.pull(DdmlibAndroidDeviceController.kt:254)
        at com.google.testing.platform.executor.DeviceControllerProxy$pull$2.invoke(DeviceControllerProxy.kt:82)
        at com.google.testing.platform.executor.DeviceControllerProxy$pull$2.invoke(DeviceControllerProxy.kt:82)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.common.noop.NoopDiagnosticsScope.recordEvent(NoopDiagnosticsScope.kt:35)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent(Telemetry.kt:66)
        at com.google.testing.platform.executor.DeviceControllerProxy.pull(DeviceControllerProxy.kt:79)
        at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.host.additionaltestoutput.AndroidAdditionalTestOutputPlugin.copyAdditionalTestOutputsFromDeviceToHost(AndroidAdditionalTestOutputPlugin.kt:222)
        at com.android.tools.utp.plugins.host.additionaltestoutput.AndroidAdditionalTestOutputPlugin.afterAll(AndroidAdditionalTestOutputPlugin.kt:206)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycle$onAfterAll$1$2$1.invoke(PluginLifecycle.kt:180)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycle$onAfterAll$1$2$1.invoke(PluginLifecycle.kt:179)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycleKt$invokeOrThrow$1.invoke(PluginLifecycle.kt:213)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycleKt$invokeOrThrow$1.invoke(PluginLifecycle.kt:212)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.common.noop.NoopDiagnosticsScope.recordEvent(NoopDiagnosticsScope.kt:35)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent(Telemetry.kt:105)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent$default(Telemetry.kt:98)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycleKt.invokeOrThrow(PluginLifecycle.kt:212)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycleKt.invokeOrThrow$default(PluginLifecycle.kt:205)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycle$onAfterAll$1.invoke(PluginLifecycle.kt:179)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycle$onAfterAll$1.invoke(PluginLifecycle.kt:173)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.common.noop.NoopDiagnosticsScope.recordEvent(NoopDiagnosticsScope.kt:35)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent(Telemetry.kt:105)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent$default(Telemetry.kt:98)
        at com.google.testing.platform.plugin.PluginLifecycle.onAfterAll(PluginLifecycle.kt:173)
        at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor$execute$3.invoke(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:83)
        at com.google.testing.platform.executor.SingleDeviceExecutor$execute$3.invoke(SingleDeviceExecutor.kt:82)
        at com.google.testing.platform.result.TestResultListenerManager.afterTestSuite(TestResultListenerManager.kt:140)
        at com.google.testing.platform.RunnerImpl.run(RunnerImpl.kt:118)
        at com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy$run$4.invoke(NonInteractiveServerStrategy.kt:80)
        at com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy$run$4.invoke(NonInteractiveServerStrategy.kt:79)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.common.noop.NoopDiagnosticsScope.recordEvent(NoopDiagnosticsScope.kt:35)
        at com.google.testing.platform.core.telemetry.TelemetryKt.recordEvent(Telemetry.kt:66)
        at com.google.testing.platform.server.strategy.NonInteractiveServerStrategy.run(NonInteractiveServerStrategy.kt:79)
        at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt$main$4.invokeSuspend(Main.kt:67)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt.main(Main.kt:66)
        at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt.main$default(Main.kt:34)
        at com.google.testing.platform.main.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.google.testing.platform.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:149)



Test results saved as file:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/xxxx/app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/S21(AVD)%20-%2012/test-result.pb. Inspect these results in Android Studio by selecting Run > Import Tests From File from the menu bar and importing test-result.pb.
Platform error occurred when running the UTP test suite

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The error message looks like it's a storage issue, but the emulator should have enough storage. This is how I started the emulator:

```
emulator -avd S21 -memory 2048 -wipe-data -no-boot-anim -cache-size 1000 -noaudio -no-window -partition-size 8192 &
```

and this is the device creation

```
avdmanager create avd --force -c 2G -k "system-images;android-32;google_apis;x86_64" -n S21
```

Then the gradle script is called like this:

```
./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

When I manually build the universal apk, install it via adb and then run the instrumentation tests it works. But to my understanding it's supposed to work without having to manually install the app.

What is the problem?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35225068/7953908 ) may help, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem is that the emulator takes a lot of time to start, so the instrumentation test fails because it cannot install the APK while the emulator is booting

`Message: Failed to install APKs: UNKNOWN`

I adapted the solution from a comment here [Detect when Android emulator is fully booted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634041/detect-when-android-emulator-is-fully-booted) to delay the next steps until the emulator is fully booted:

```
emulator -avd S21 -memory 2048 -wipe-data -no-boot-anim -cache-size 1000 -noaudio -no-window -partition-size 8192 &

adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done;'
```

Comment: Using the Jenkins android emulator plugin to start an emulator did not work and just caused loads of errors. So I'm still open for better solutions but this one works for now.

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar error on Android 10 when switching between Git branches, then trying to run some Instrumentation tests:

```
Unknown platform error occurred when running the UTP test suite. Please check logs for details.
```

The solution was to uninstall the test APK and then re-install it by running a UI test. The steps are as follows:

**With the phone UI:**

1. On the Home screen, press the "Apps" button, or swipe up. Then launch the Settings app.
2. Click on "Apps and Notifications" ➔ "See All apps" or "Applications List"
3. Scroll down the list to locate your test APK, which will normally have a title of something like `"com.company.app.test"` and it will have a generic green Android icon.
4. Click this test APK ➔ Uninstall ➔ OK.
5. Now run your UI test. Android Studio will reinstall a fresh version of the test APK.

**Using adb on the command line:**

```bash
# Replace "com.company.app.test" with your APK test package ID
adb uninstall com.company.app.test
```

Comment: manually uninstalling the app and test apks worked for me

Comment: .IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package

Answer (score 4):

There may be some reasons for this error:

1. The Android Gradle plugin version is not compatible with Gradle version.
2. If you use wireless debugging try using USB debugging.

Comment: For me it failed on a physical device when running over wireless debugging.

Answer (score 3):

In my case my emulator ran out of space, apparently the "testing apk" files are placed in the emulator before installing them, and they stay there after the test finishes. So I had to remove those files and then it worked again.

Comment: Or add space in AVD settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me running `adb kill-server` solved the problem